# Save Pygame simulation as an mp4 file

Tags: python, animation, video, pygame, mp4

I used pygame to simulate the movement of rain and I was wondering how I can save this simulation as a mp4/gif file because I want to include it in a powerpoint presentation. Is there a function or specific command in other Python packages and libraries I can use besides screenrecording my screen? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Directly from only PyGame it's not possible.  But you could use the `pygame.Surface.save()` function to write every frame to a file, e.g.:

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
WINDOW_FPS    = 30

### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

frame_count = 0
exiting     = False
clock       = pygame.time.Clock()
while not exiting:
    # handle events
    # paint the screen

    # save the frame
    frame_count += 1
    filename = "screen_%04d.png" % ( frame_count )
    pygame.image.save( window, filename )

    clock.tick( WINDOW_FPS )  # limit FPS
```

Then use something like `ffmpeg` to convert all those still-frames back to an animation:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -s 400x400 -i screen_%04d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  window_video.mp4
```

Note the size and frame-rate `-r 30` should match the `WINDOW_*` variables used, and the `%04d` length of the frame-number match what's output.